MapRequestPayload cannot acces information with hyphen
I have an app in Symfony 6.4 where I use attribute MapRequestPayload to parse incoming data. Until now it worked fine but I've started using external service (mailgun) to get some data and there is a problem mapping event-data varaible part. I cannot change the way data is sent to me. So everythime i want to use #[MapRequestPayload] data cannot have hypen in structure or it will not be mapped.
I recieve request with body:
{
   'signature': { ... },
   'event-data': { ... }

I'm trying to map it with #[MapRequestPayload] UpdateEmailStatusInput.
Constructor I use in controller public function updateStatus(#[MapRequestPayload] UpdateEmailStatusInput $emailStatusInput)
class UpdateEmailStatusInput
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Assert\NotBlank] public array $signature,
        #[Assert\NotBlank] public array $eventData,
    ) {
    }
}

signature variable works fine, but eventData does not works (it is blank):
signature: array:3 []
eventData: null

I cannot make variable $event-data because PHP think it is #event (minus) const data.
Is ther some kind of config or workaraound to make it work out of the box? For the moment I'm using regural $request->getContent() to get the event-data variable.

You could try a SerializedName annotation, as shown here.

This totally works. I thought it won't decode another name with hyphen but it got all the structure.

Using SerializedName as sugessted resolved the issue. The whole structure is decoded, even names with hyphen deep in the structure.
So Input class now look like this:
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

class UpdateEmailStatusInput
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Assert\NotBlank]
        public array $signature,
        #[SerializedName('event-data')]
        #[Assert\NotBlank]
        public array $event,
    ) {
    }
}

and is called from controller:
public function updateStatus(#[MapRequestPayload] UpdateEmailStatusInput $emailStatusInput)
